# Create a PING Monitor in WPF Application - With DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, monitoring, ping

I'm new in the forum. Sorry for my English... It's not very well.

Please, I read the article: 
[How to Perform Multiple "Pings" in Parallel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405848/how-to-perform-multiple-pings-in-parallel-using-c-sharp)

Please, someone give me a help and to explain how can I populate a WPF Datagrid to monitoring a list of IP's ?

I'm build a class:

...
        public class ServerMonitor
        {
            public  string ID { set; get; }
            public  string Timeout { set; get; }
            public  string IP { set; get; }
            public  string TTL { set; get; }
        }
...

In main method I got it show data in datagridview.

```
        MonitorPing.PingAddressesAsync(new List<IPAddress>() {
            IPAddress.Parse ("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"),
            IPAddress.Parse ("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"),
            IPAddress.Parse ("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"),
            IPAddress.Parse ("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX")
        }, delegate (Task<List<PingReply>> tpr)
        {
            var lr = tpr.Result;

            foreach (var pr in lr)
            {
                //This correct
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,(ThreadStart)(() => dataGrid.Items.Add(new ServerMonitor { ID = pr.Buffer.ToString(), Timeout = pr.Status.ToString(), IP = pr.Address.ToString(), TTL = pr.RoundtripTime.ToString() })));
            }
        });
    }
```

At this point, it's all right.

But how do I get the data to be updated in real time? I use a while, use a System.Timer...

Tks and sorry for anything!

Comment: Where are you stuck? Try it and if you run into problems, come back with a specific question. We're not here to write applications for you. You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @itsme86 Granted I'm not well versed in C or WPF, but "Please, someone give me a help and to explain how can I populate a WPF Datagrid to monitoring a list of IP's ?" seems like a specific enough question. They are asking for how to do a certain thing.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman I disagree. "How do I build a house?" seems like a question about something specific as well, but what you really need to do is something like "I'm trying to build a house, but while laying the foundation, X is happening. Here's the process I'm using to lay the foundation. Can someone point out where the process is flawed and how to correct it?"

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for replys. Sorry if i'm not to specific, but I can try, and I consider this as a first step!

Comment: @itsme86 Okay. Again, I don't know anything about C or WPF, so I don't really know how specific that is.

Comment: So after I answered your question and explained how to "get the data to be updated in real time" by using the ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged interface you append your question to ask that same thing instead of making an effort to learn about how this is achieved in a WPF app? Are you expecting someone will provide you with full code listing?

Comment: Hi Dean Kuga, Thanks for your replay! I'm just try to reproduce your tip... I need more time for create a solution. I do not mean that someone do the code, but I confess that I am lost to this solution. Give me more time to create a solution :D Tks!

Answer (score 0):

To display a list of items in the DataGrid with values that are automatically updated in the UI you will need to bind your DataGrid to an ObservableCollection of objects which implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

The code which performs the actual pinging would reside in your ViewModel which will also contain the ObservableCollection. That code would periodically iterate through the objects in that ObservableCollection and update the desired public Properties of each object with ping results and these values will be automatically updated in the DataGrid because they implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Hello Dean Kga! Thanks a lot!