# C# Need Help Returning Lowest Ping using SendAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, console, ping, sendasync

I have the following code that is working and pings all of the Runescape game servers and returns a list in the console of the ip addresses and the respective 'roundtrip' time taken.

EDIT 'IGNORE SOME OF THE OLD COMMENTS'

I am having trouble with the following:

A) How can I return the lowest ping out of all of the servers and write it to the console?

B) How can i return the original hostname or 'number' of the current 'server.ToString()' across methods?

```
    public void buttonClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Ping();     
    }


    public static void Ping()
    {
        for (int server = 1; server <= 110; server++)
        {
            string hostname = "oldschool" + server.ToString() + ".runescape.com";

            // Get an object that will block the main thread.
            AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            // Ping's the local machine.
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();

            // When the PingCompleted event is raised,
            // the PingCompletedCallback method is called.
            pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            //Console.WriteLine("Send Before Async.");

            // Send the ping asynchronously.
            // Use the waiter as the user token.
            // When the callback completes, it can wake up this thread.
            pingSender.SendAsync(hostname, 1000, waiter);

            //Console.WriteLine("Ping example completed.");
        }
    }

    private static void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the operation was canceled, display a message to the user.
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping canceled.");
            // Let the main thread resume. 
            // UserToken is the AutoResetEvent object that the main thread 
            // is waiting for.
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }
        // If an error occurred, display the exception to the user.
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping failed:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
            // Let the main thread resume. 
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }
        PingReply reply = e.Reply;
        DisplayReply(reply);

        // Let the main thread resume.
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }

    public static void DisplayReply(PingReply reply)
    {
        List<long> lag = new List<long>();

        if (reply == null)
        return;

        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", reply.Status);

        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", reply.Address);
            Console.WriteLine("Ping: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Do you need all that call back stuff? You could have about 5 lines of code doing all that using PLinq and the synchronous SendPing method.

Comment: I think i had a problem using Async & returning all of the reply details at the time, pretty new to C# so it's kinda getting messy for me atm!

Answer (score 0):

I restructured your code so it should work.  I also made pings run in parallel which should speed up results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }
    }
    public class State
    {
        public string ip { get; set;}
        public decimal roundTripTime { get; set; }
        public IPStatus status { get;set;}
    }
    public class myPing
    {
        static const int NUMBER_SERVERS = 110;
        public static List<State> states { get; set; }
        public static int count = 0;
        public myPing()
        {

            AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            for (int server = 1; server <= NUMBER_SERVERS; server++)
            {
                string hostname = "oldschool" + server.ToString() + ".runescape.com";

                // Get an object that will block the main thread.

                // Ping's the local machine.
                Ping pingSender = new Ping();


                // When the PingCompleted event is raised,
                // the PingCompletedCallback method is called.
                pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);

                // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
                string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                //Console.WriteLine("Send Before Async.");

                // Send the ping asynchronously.
                // Use the waiter as the user token.
                // When the callback completes, it can wake up this thread.
                pingSender.SendAsync(hostname, 1000, waiter);

                //Console.WriteLine("Ping example completed.");
            }
            waiter.WaitOne();
            DisplayReply(states);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the operation was canceled, display a message to the user.
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ping canceled.");
                // Let the main thread resume. 
                // UserToken is the AutoResetEvent object that the main thread 
                // is waiting for.
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            }
            // If an error occurred, display the exception to the user.
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ping failed:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
                // Let the main thread resume. 
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            }
            PingReply reply = e.Reply;

            State state = new State();

            Object thisLock = new Object();

            lock (thisLock)
            {
               states.Add(state);
            }
            state.ip = reply.Address.ToString();
            state.roundTripTime = reply.RoundtripTime;
            state.status = reply.Status;

            count++;
            // Let the main thread resume.
            if (count == NUMBER_SERVERS)
            {
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            }
        }

        public static void DisplayReply(List<State> replies)
        {
            foreach (State reply in replies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", reply.status);

                if (reply.status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", reply.ip);
                    Console.WriteLine("Ping: {0}", reply.roundTripTime);
                }
            }
            State shortest = replies.OrderBy(x => x.roundTripTime).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("Shortest Route IP : '{0}'  Time : '{1}'", shortest.ip.ToString(), shortest.roundTripTime.ToString() );
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and sorry for the late response, I appreciate it. I have tried running the code that you have kindly re-written for me. I seemed to get nothing written to the console at all, not sure where it's going wrong!

Comment: Looked at my answer at following posting.  the code I know works.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431475/how-to-do-network-ping-net

Comment: If you add the following code to previous posting you will get the lowest round trip time : I added a few line to the code in previous posting to get shortest time :            MyPing ping = new MyPing(dt);

            List<PingReply> replies = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<List<PingReply>>("Reply") != null).Select(x => x.Field<List<PingReply>>("Reply")).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

            long ShortTime = replies.Min(x => x.RoundtripTime);